Can we make the joins on different datatype columns, as when using the product.comments in rails console
I have implemented the polymorphic and called the comments using the product.comments
But I am not able to.
Product has many comments and comments are polymorphic with commentable.
Tried to create the comments from the products, not able to fetch the comments.
